# Replacing some values before build starts

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

How would I replace automatically `""` with `string.Empty` for the whole solution/project? I would like this to exclude attributes from replacing that. How would I implement that in case of there is no such feature / extension like that?

Comment: Try: Ctrl + Shift + H

Comment: How does this fits my requirements?